# What is Mylar used for in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I know this might be a newbie question, but I'm curious about the use of Mylar/Mylyn in Eclipse.  I am going through Eclipse's functionality, and I see interesting tools/shortcuts for Mylyn(like "make landmark" ).

Especially, if I'm a single-developer on my machine, should I use Mylar? Or is it for SVN, etc?

thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also understand your interest. I've always noticed Mylyn, but I never bothered with it until recently.
Eclipse Mylyn is a plugin for Task management. It also has some very nifty features like Storing active context.
The integration with task management tools like Bugzilla and Github issues is amazing. look at this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Mylyn/article.html) from Lars Vogel for more information, as well as the [Mylyn Users Guide.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide) Its one of those tools that once you start using, you can't stop.